# Multiple PHP frameworks on same platform.

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, yii

We are building a global platform for users and expect around 10,000 to 50,000 users per day.

Most of our modules are written in a particular framework. Now we are expanding some more modules and with an additional team of developerssome new set of developers. This new of developers are however recommending using another php framework for the additional modules.

There is also a business need to integrate earlier modules with the new  modules even from coding perspective - in the sense output from one module (written in framework I) might be an input in another module written in ( Framework II).

Does this community sees any issues in this ? or shall we stick to only php framework I as that is where we started..

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically you could have both frameworks running on the same site, by placing the Cake code in a subdirectory (so all URLs start with something like http://my.domain.com/cake/), and adding a RewriteBase to the .htaccess in that directory.

However, from a (code) management point of view this is an **absolute terrible** idea. New devs or not, they should stick to the existing framework. But that discussion does not belong here (is there actually a StackExchange site for project management...?)